# Can I downvote if OP not responded?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, asking-questions

Can I downvote the OP if he didn't respond or comment after asking the question? How to handle  a situation if OP asks the question and left (for few days)?

Comment: I'm assuming there is a problem with the question? It's not clear somehow and that's why you really downvote? Or just because the user left? In any case, they are your downvotes. You do as you please.

Comment: Please don't downvote for the user's absence, we don't know the current situation of the user.

Comment: @Bart Sometimes the OP asks the question and will left . Then the answered users would be idiots.

Comment: If you leave a request for clarification and it goes unanswered then a DV for "question is unclear" may well be justified. But otherwise no IMO.

Comment: @SubinJacob Nope, why? The content is still there for all the world to enjoy. If there is no problem with the question itself, I would personally not downvote.

Comment: @Bart But it always a bad experience not to get response after answering a long problem.

Comment: @Bart See this Question. I suppose the OP never came back. http://stackoverflow.com/q/20469416/1923685

Comment: Basically you are free to vote as you like (just suspicous voting patterns are forbidden). But I like Bathshebas approach more.

Comment: @SubinJacob but look at the profile. 35 questions, no answers. How many accepted answers?

Comment: Why? You've provided content for the rest of the world to enjoy. If your answer is good, you'll be rewarded for it. The OP doesn't matter all that much from that point on. Don't start punishing people for no good reason. If their questions are unclear, fair enough. But other than that...meh.

Comment: @SubinJacob That question was from 22 hour ago. Patience please.

Comment: @Bart I never did.Now, Not going to do!

Comment: @Bart Can you tell me then why I got downvote for this question. I believe these downvotes show the attitude against my idea. Not because the question isn't clear. rite?

Comment: You'd have to ask the downvoters, not me. I could take a guess, but it wouldn't be more than that.

Comment: @bart Everyone downvotes just to show their dislike to the question. Thats what I felt.

Comment: your question is clear, [voting is different in meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: @SubinJacob: yes, I downvoted because I believe that you really shouldn't be downvoting questions because of a lack of response. On the other hand, _if (and __only__ if)_ it would otherwise be unanswerable or off-topic if the OP did not respond and you're just waiting to see whether the question will be improved, go ahead and downvote it.

Comment: +1 because the question is on topic and clear, even though I don't think you should down vote for this reason.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I didn't do so. Just asked here to know. thats all

Comment: @SubinJacob: sorry if I implied that you _were_ doing that -- that was not my intention. I was just responding to the hypothetical situation that you had given.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Its k. I can understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your vote should only reflect the question quality, not the perceived tardiness of the OP.

You can always check the OP's profile.

Comment: I assume the last paragraph refers to seeing when they were last active?